# can someone tell me why this page constantly prints the console log output?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, react-hooks

Update: i put the function inside a hook and used a constant variable to hold the data instead of useState.

When i come on this page, when i look at the console its a never ending list of the console output, why doesnt it just do it once ? i only called the function once.

```js
import { auth } from "../../components/firebase";
import { database } from "../../components/firebase";
import { ref, child, get } from "firebase/database";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function Dashboard() {
  const dbRef = ref(database);

  const getData = () => {
    get(child(dbRef, "users/"))
      .then((snapshot) => {
        const data = (snapshot.val());
        console.log(data);
      })

      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() =>{
    getData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div>Properties</div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: How often do you want to call `getData`? If it's only once in the beginning, try wrapping it in [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) with `[]` as dependencies

Comment: I'm quite new to React myself, but I think the problem is that calling `setUserInfo` tells it to rerender, which means it will execute the whole function again and in turn call `getData()` a 2nd, 3rd, etc time. So the loop is render -> getData -> setUserInfo -> render

Comment: i put it inside the use effect, but then it doesnt set the user data, its null

Comment: instead of using state, i just assigned the snapshot to a constant, that solved the problem. thanks

Comment: code had syntax error(unbalanced braces). ensure it reflects your real code, otherwise hints might be unhelpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the function gets called by react many times on every re-render. If there is something you want to run once, or when some data changes, use `useEffect` hook as follows

Put `getData()` in `useEffects`.

```
import { auth } from "../../components/firebase";
import { database } from "../../components/firebase";
import { ref, child, get } from "firebase/database";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function Dashboard() {
  const dbRef = ref(database);
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState([]);

  const getData = () => {
    get(child(dbRef, "users/"))
      .then((snapshot) => {
        setUserInfo(snapshot.val());
        console.log(userInfo);
      })

      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

  useEffect(()=>{
    getData();
  }, [dbRef])

  return (
    <>
      <div>Properties</div>
    </>
  );
}
```

The following runs when the variables passed to useEffects changes `[dbRef]`

Comment: Hi, with this solution, the userInfo object is null when i console log it. So i just store the data inside a const variable instead, that solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If the function is called without ending, it means the component is render constantly. The component is render if the parent component renders or if the props change. Check the render of the parent component using a console.log("...")